# Parsing Unexpected Fields in XML to a Struct using Go

Tags: xml, parsing, go

Lets say we have an XML document that looks like this, which has an unexpected tag `<custom1>` on `<item>`

```
<item>
  <name>...</name>
  <price>...</price>
  <custom1>...</custom1>
</item>
```

The struct to parse this looks like this

```
type Item struct {
    Name     string   `xml:"name"`
    Price    string   `xml:"price"`
}
```

I don't have `Custom1` in there since I'm not expecting it. However, is it possible to capture the remaining tags OR the raw representation of the `<item>` inside the `Item` struct?

Answer (score 2):

Use a field with `,innerxml` tag:

```
type Item struct {
    Name  string `xml:"name"`
    Price string `xml:"price"`
    Other string `xml:",innerxml"`
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Io2CDjSiwx.